# Having an error while training data using LinearClassifier. [Labels must be <= n_classes - 1]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

To see the code open the colab link below.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H1QW_VOCIB9hvhQlg0zCkKlsT8aXgcUW?usp=sharing

[Click to open image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrXB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you are trying to predict the variable 'expenses'. If i'm not wrong, this variable is continuous you can't use classification algorithms to predict it. LinearRegressor would be more suitable in this case